# Dash (Plotly) assets files are not reading after deploy to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I created simple app from dash framework in python and deployed into heroku.

Here i want to show some set of images & stored in assets folder.

```
/assets:
- image1.jpg
- image2.jpg
app.py
```

Images are not showing in heroku app.

Code line : `html.Img(src=app.get_asset_url('image1.jpg'))),`

Thanks...

Comment: check your spelling of "/asseRts"

Comment: it was assets only not asserts @jjsantoso